# How to dynamically change what's exposed in a preload script?

Tags: electron

I have a `BrowserWindow` with a preload script.

I want to expose different things in the preload script depending on what page I have loaded.

In my app, either I load page A which gets navigated to page B, or I load page B from the beginning.

I was considering passing additional arguments to my preload via:

```
{
    preload: "path_to_preload.js",
    additionalArguments: ["onPageB"]
}
```

And then my preload can do:

```
const onPageB = process.argv.find(arg => arg === "onPageB");
```

And then I set up my preload script based on what page B needs.

However, my preload script can be loaded with page A initially, so `onPageB` will be `false`, and then it's stuck at false even when I navigate to page B.

What I really need is to dynamically respond to navigations. (Ideally, I would be able to dynamically switch out preload scripts, but I don't think that's supported, or is possible from an architectural standpoint).

To detect navigations, normally, I would do:

```
getMyWebContents().on("did-navigate", (e, url) => ...);
```

But I can't use `WebContents` from the Renderer process.

I can obviously query what page I'm on via `ipcRenderer.invoke`, but I can't just do that on load. I need to do that when the page navigates as well, which seems to suggest I have to detect that from the main process, and then let my preload script know that.

But how can I do that. Is `executeJavaScript` a solution here where I call a function in my preload to trigger the changes? Not sure if that will work correctly, or is even a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron developer mentioned that preload scripts get reexecuted for every navigation (which retrospectively is obvious).

Thus, we can just access `location.href` in the preload and figure out what page we're on.